# How to remove in OneSignal modal view which appears in the Android app, when app is opened and user is receiving PN in that moment? (react-native)

Tags: react-native, onesignal

I'm using `OneSignal` for push notification in my `react-native` app.

Is it possible to remove modal view which appears in the Android app, when app is opened and user is receiving PN in that moment?

I want to use my own modal view instead.
I checked official documentation, but didn't find any information about it.

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, in order to remove this modal view in Android use:

OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(2)